# Using Selenium with Pytest for a Django 2.2 project running in Docker

Tags: django, selenium, docker, pytest

I'm trying to use Pytest with the Django plugin and Selenium to test a Django 2.2 project that is running in Docker but I'm unable to get Selenium to connect to the test server. Selenium keeps returning "Address not available" when I try to connect using the setup below.

My Docker compose is:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - selenium
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: local_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

I've defined `DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS=django` in my `.django` env file, and setup a fixture in `conftest.py` for the Selenium remote webdriver:

```
import environ
import pytest

from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


env = environ.Env()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def selenium() -> Remote:
    driver = Remote(
        command_executor=env('SELENIUM_HOST', default='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'),
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    )
    yield driver
```

My test case, using my `selenium` fixture and the `live_server` fixture provided by Django-PyTest:

```
import pytest

class TestDashboard:
    def test_loads(self, selenium, live_server):
        selenium.get(live_server.url)
        assert My Site' in selenium.title
```

raises `OSError: [Errno 99] Address not available` in the `live_server` constructor.

Amongst other things, I've also tried to use the `StaticLiveServerTestCase` class directly, omitting `live_server` and my `selenium` fixture, but this hasn't worked much better:

```
import pytest

from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase

from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


class TestDashboardView(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.host = 'django'
        cls.selenium = Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        )
        super().setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_page_loads(self):
        self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url)
        assert "My Site" in self.selenium.title
```

This version of the test also raises `OSError: [Errno 99] Address not available`.

Does anyone here have any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong and how I can go about fixing it? It'd be really great to get Selenium working alongside of my existing backend tests.

Answer (score 2):

Think I've figured this out. Rather than use the pytest-django `live_server` fixture, I've add my own that leverages the existing `LiveServer` class.

Here's my additional fixture:

```
import pytest
import socket

from pytest_django.live_server_helper import LiveServer

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_server() -> LiveServer:
    addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    server = LiveServer(addr)
    yield server
    server.stop()
```

You may also need to add the Django container's ip to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. I do this like so:

```
if env("USE_DOCKER") == "yes":
    import socket

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())]
```

Comment: I have the same setup but I'm struggling to get this to work. I use your fixture and then pass the test_server as argument to my test. Then I run         ```browser.get(test_server.url)``` where browser is ```browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )``` .... But when my website opens I get ```A server error occured. Please contact the administrator``` . Any idea what I could do? Or how did you get this work? Thank you!